# Custom Bot always replies with an error

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am trying to send a webhook out from Teams, which is apparently accomplished with a [Custom Bot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/custombot). I am able to get the bot created and then I can do `@botname stuff` and the endpoint receives a payload.

However, the bot immediately replies with "Sorry, there was a problem encountered with your request". I get this error if I point the "Callback URL" to a requestb.in url or if I point it to my endpoint. This leads me to suspect the bot is expecting some specific response from the endpoint, but this isn't documented. My endpoint responds with a 202 and some json. Requestb.in responds with a 200 and "ok".

So, is it true that the bot requires a specific response payload and if so what is this payload?

That link above mentions `Your custom bot will need to reply asynchronously to the HTTP request from Microsoft Teams. It will have 5 seconds to reply to the message before the connection is terminated.` But there is no indication of how to satisfy this request, unless the custom bot will need to reply synchronously.

Comment: I suspect it doesn't like the `204`. Have you tried pushing back a simple `200`? A `204` implies the sever accepted the request but won't be returning any content.

Comment: Yea, that is my suspicion as well, but I have no control over the return payload. This web service processes the requests asynchronously. The response is a uuid for the request for tracking, but I don't really need to capture this in Teams.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur, Sorry, it's actually a 20 (post updated). The request is processed asynchronously, processed and then we'll make a call back to Teams with a follow up message. Technically ALL of the 200 response codes are success so Teams should consider them a success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return a JSON response with the keys 'text' and 'type' as shown in the example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/custombot#example-reply-message)

```
{
"type": "message",
"text": "This is a reply!"
}
```

In case you are using NodeJS, you can try [this sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44049178/2102114)

I created an azure function in C# as the callback for the custom bot and was initially sending back a json string but that didnt work. Finally I had to set the response object's `Content` and `ContentType` to get it working (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40409222/incoming-webhook-for-private-messages-in-microsoft-teams)). Here is the code for a simple bot that echoes back what the user types in the channel, feel free to adapt it to your scenario.

**Custom MS Teams bot example code using azure functions**

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    // parse query parameter
    string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
        .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
        .Value;

    // Get request body
    dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
    log.Info(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
    // Set name to query string or body data
    name = name ?? data?.text;
    Response res = new Response();
    res.type = "Message";
    res.text = $"You said:{name}";
    var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res));
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    return response;
}

public class Response {
    public string type;
    public string text;
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but not the answer I wanted to hear :) I can't change the format of the response payload. I think the documentation is a little vague, "Example response" to me is not a "defined" response. The doc implies you *could* respond with that value not that you *must*.

Comment: @nomadic_squirrel thats what I thought initially. Attempts at sending just a string back failed and hence I fell back on the superstition of just following the example exactly. Maybe the vague documentation is a way of making us use custom bots less and the bot framework more :) ;)